# Dependency injection into controller using $inject

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, inject

I am trying to inject a number of dependencies into a controller as part of a code refactoring process inline with John Papa's Style Guide. Right now, our controller looks like this:

```
.controller('alerting-settings.mainController', [
    '$scope',
    '$timeout',
    '$location',    
    '$document',
    '$window',

    function($scope,
             $timeout,
             $location,
             $document,
             $window) {
```

[According to John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection), it should be done more like this:

```
/* recommended */
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

DashboardController.$inject = ['$location', '$routeParams', 'common', 'dataservice'];

function DashboardController($location, $routeParams, common, dataservice) {
}
```

So what happens when I refactor? I end up with this:

```
angular.module('app.alerting-settings')

.controller('alerting-settings.mainController', alerting-settings.mainController);

    alerting-settings.mainController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$timeout',
    '$location',    
    '$document',
    '$window'],
```

Problem is that I get console errors now:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place the $inject after the Controller function.

Comment: I just did that but I still get "senses-lib.js:70 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.alerting-settings' is not available!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename `alerting-settings` by `alertingSettings` everywhere.

You can use use "-" in file name but never in controller/service names because they are "functions" and in javascript you cant have a dash in function name

--> `function alerting-settings()` is not a valid function name.